# systemd fails to install on raspbian python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, raspbian, systemd

I want to install the `systemd` ([github](https://github.com/mosquito/python-systemd)) library.

However, executing

```
sudo pip3 install systemd
```

Leads to this error:

> Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-c97m6cn0/systemd/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-gqnrg4wd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-c97m6cn0/systemd/

I tried to upgrade the setuptools, but this did not resolve my issue:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Here the full console output:

> `$ sudo pip3 install systemd Collecting systemd`
>   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/c2/2195b049effd866b5d26926e672be83fc6f3263aa71ea0639e8eab44851e/systemd-0.16.1.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: systemd   Running setup.py
>   bdist_wheel for systemd ... error   Complete output from command
>   /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-11re058x/systemd/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d
>   /tmp/tmpg851h3qzpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
>   /usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown
>   distribution option: 'build_requires'
>       warnings.warn(msg)   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   creating build   creating build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5
>   creating build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd   copying
>   systemd/daemon.py -> build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd   copying
>   systemd/journal.py -> build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd   copying
>   systemd/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd   running
>   build_ext   building 'systemd._daemon' extension   creating
>   build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5   creating
>   build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread
>   -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-RUbMX3/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c systemd/_daemon.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd/_daemon.o
>   systemd/_daemon.c:539:31: fatal error: systemd/sd-daemon.h: No such
>   file or directory    #include 
>                                    ^   compilation terminated.   error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for
>   systemd   Running setup.py clean for systemd Failed to build systemd
>   Installing collected packages: systemd   Running setup.py install for
>   systemd ... error
>       Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-11re058x/systemd/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-lirhgtsu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       /usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'build_requires'
>         warnings.warn(msg)
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5
>       creating build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd
>       copying systemd/daemon.py -> build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd
>       copying systemd/journal.py -> build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd
>       copying systemd/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd
>       running build_ext
>       building 'systemd._daemon' extension
>       creating build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5
>       creating build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd
>       arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-RUbMX3/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c systemd/_daemon.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/systemd/_daemon.o
>       systemd/_daemon.c:539:31: fatal error: systemd/sd-daemon.h: No such file or directory
>        #include 
>                                      ^
>       compilation terminated.
>       error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-11re058x/systemd/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
> ```
>
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-lirhgtsu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-11re058x/systemd/

Comment: Please post the full error trace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant part of the error is

```
fatal error: systemd/sd-daemon.h: No such file or directory
```

Install `libsystemd-dev` using `apt` first and you should be good to go:

```
sudo apt install libsystemd-dev
```

Comment: installing `libsystemd-dev` eventually worked for me on a Raspberry Pi Zero W, but I needed to install and update `apt-file` to make the packages available for installation. Details here: https://askubuntu.com/a/851194

Answer (score 1):

This command will install `systemd` in your system.

```
sudo apt-get install python-systemd
```

Comment: This simple solution worked for me in jessie (python3-systemd).